# rails server for long-term requests to 3rd party API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, thin, unicorn

Please, advise server for long-term requests to 3rd party API server. 
When I use unicorn, sometimes number of workers isn't enough and clients requests are broken by timeout.

Thin, Rainbows!, anything else. What is better?
I found async-rails, but it has 'stack level too deep' problem, even if I disable assets

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make your requests as a background job ([Resque with Redis](https://github.com/defunkt/resque), Delayed Job), or use [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) which allows you to specify a timeout.

You can handle the timeout accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. From client, who used my api request should looks like synchronous. Timeout is set using Net::HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of https://github.com/hakanensari/async-rails and http://dev.af83.com/2011/09/20/fighting-with-eventmachine.html looks like solution what I need.